# Angular 10 doesn't let me install Angular 6 locally - package.json gets ignored

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, visual-studio-code, angular6

I have an `Angular 6.0.7` project that I've pulled from our repository. Globally, I have `Angular 10.0.4` installed. When I navigate to the project's directory and do an `npm install` from within `VS code`, I would expect `Angular 6.0.7` to be installed as a local instance since that's what my `package.json` file references. However, `npm install` always results in `Angular 10.0.4` being installed locally. Even if I specify `npm install @angular/cli@6.0.7`, `Angular 10.0.4` still gets installed. On install, I get the following error messages:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-spKHSBQIxxS81N/O21WmuXA2F6wppUCsutpzenOeZzOCCJ5gEfcbqJP983IrpLXzYmXnMUa6J03SubcNPdKrlg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-spKHSBQIxxS81N/O21WmuXA2F6wppUCsutpzenOeZzOCCJ5gEfcbqJP983IrpLXzYmXnMUa6J03SubcNPdKrlg== but got sha512-2lGfU4gymmhXRUiPLeQlnlkMaSY8azJB9W8e/vFp44AlAOEvzf6XiBUoTHO9NBM4OVlehybxDM9B4SwLBh42mw==. (10271 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-31T21_03_01_732Z-debug.log
```

This installs `Angular 10.0.4` and results in my project not working. If I do an `ng serve --port 5200`, I get the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-8jruJl\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Maybe it has to do with the EINTEGRITY error, or maybe it's something to do w/ Angular 10 incompatibility issues w older projects. Any ideas?

**My package.json file:**

```
    {
      "name": "cafe",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --open",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
        "angular5-toaster": "^1.0.2",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
        "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
        "stream": "0.0.2",
        "wijmo": "file:../../../../../programs/wijmo/wijmo-5.20191.603/NpmImages/wijmo-commonjs-min/wijmo-5.20191.603-rc.tgz",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
        "typescript": "~2.7.2",
        "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.3.0",
        "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular` in an attempt to fix this, but am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to delete `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\@angular-devkit` please and reinstall?

Comment: I don't have an `@angular-devkit` file in `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\``. In that case, what command should I run, and should I run it in a global session of `Command Prompt` (global instance) or from `VS Code` in my project directory (local instance)?

Comment: try `npm link` in both global session and VS Code scope please

Comment: Global fails because no package.json file in the npm-cache folder. Local partially runs but gives the errors: `npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/file-saver/-/file-saver-1.3.3.tgz failed, reason: write EPROTO 16424:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-31T22_13_23_042Z-debug.log`. ng serve still fails